# onCreate function does not work

Tags: android

I have developed a simple android app that load a image on a url in internet and show it in a imageview to user (that is all) , when I put all my codes in onCreate function the app does not work while putting the same code in onStart the app works and show the image....
i have another problem like this before: when i want to change a textview text property while the app is starting (using onCreate function) i failed and the app crashed but using the same code in onStart solve the problem, please help me I have stuck in this damn problem.
can you explane why this happen?
my codes

```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        try {
            URL url=new URL("http://player.arsenal.com/site_media/images     /uploaded/videothumbs/001702f8095b04cfc885ff1a79375312/552x310/idx-10.jpg");
            HttpGet httpRequest=null;
            httpRequest= new HttpGet(url.toURI());
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                    .execute(httpRequest);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
            InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }


    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         String msg = null;
        Log.d(msg, "The onStart() event");




    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some guesswork, the difference between `onCreate()` and `onStart()`: Your `imageView1` is not in the activity layout but in the fragment layout. Pending fragment transactions are executed in `super.onStart()` and the fragment gets attached to the activity. After that calling `findViewById()` on the activity view hierarchy actually finds the view and does not return null as it would in `onCreate()` phase.

Other than that, you're doing network operations on the main thread (you shouldn't) and you should be punished with `NetworkOnMainThreadException` unless you've suppressed it with `StrictMode` or `targetSdkVersion` below 11.

You're also swallowing any `Exception` there which prevents you from learning about any problems in the `try` block. Consider at least logging the exception stacktrace.

Comment: my problem is just i can not change View elements like textview or imageview while app is starting, in onCreate, but if put all my code in a function and i call it with a button that works. or put in on onStart ....

Comment: Yes. At those points in the lifecycle the fragment transaction has been run and the fragment is part of the activity view hierarchy.